# Make two elements behave like floating elements without using css property float

Tags: css, flexbox, css-float

I want to horizontally align two elements **without** using the css property float.

To be more spesific:

I want them to be horizontally aligned, floating to each side of the parent:

[image]

And, if the screen gets smaller, I want them to wrap underneath each other while still floating to each side of the parent (like with float):

[image]

Is this possible to achieve using flexbox or something like that?

Comment: Repeat after me: there is nothing wrong with using the float property.

Comment: Yeah I never said it was. I am just asking how you would do it without using it.

Comment: float is an extremely specialized property, with a very unique set of layout behaviors. I'd be surprised if you could emulate it with something like flexbox.

Comment: @BoltClock You'll be able to emulate it with CSS Grids once that's implemented, probably

Comment: @slowpoke123 if you know the width of the elements, you could use a media query to just reposition them once their widths are overlapping or their inner borders are close enough.

Comment: @BoltClock If you are interested in how, see the accepted answer

Comment: @slowpoke123: Color me surprised. Just keep in mind that you're only attempting to emulate specific floating behaviors and not the entire float model - in this case, the behavior of two competing floats, which, evidently, is easy enough with flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to make the left and right swap sides based on only a property of a child element like a real float does, without specifying `flex-direction:row-reverse;` on the wrapper. See my example for a comparison: http://codepen.io/ijstanley/pen/JWXwOy

```
<p>pseudo floats in reverse order in markup</p>
<div class="flex wrapper">
  <div class="pseudo float right">right</div>
  <div class="pseudo float left">left</div>
</div>
<p>pseudo floats in correct order in markup</p>
<div class="flex wrapper">
  <div class="pseudo float left">left</div>
  <div class="pseudo float right">right</div>
</div>
<p>pseudo floats in reverse order in markup, reverse flex direction</p>
<div class="reverse flex wrapper">
  <div class="pseudo float right">right</div>
  <div class="pseudo float left">left</div>
</div>
<p>pseudo floats in correct order in markup, reverse flex direction</p>
<div class="reverse flex wrapper">
  <div class="pseudo float left">left</div>
  <div class="pseudo float right">right</div>
</div>
<p>actual floats</p>
<div class="floater wrapper">
  <div class="real float left">left</div>
  <div class="real float right">right</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.wrapper {
  border:3px solid gray;
}

.wrapper.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.wrapper.flex.reverse {
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}

.wrapper.floater {
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper.floater::after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

.float {
  min-height:200px;
  background:red;
  border:3px solid black;
  width:300px;
}

.float.pseudo.left {
  margin-right:auto;
}

.float.real.left {
  float:left;
}

.float.real.right {
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I ended up with using pseudo floats in correct order in markup

Comment: I had a think and have updated my codepen, I've added the order property which allows the elements to swap sides, they still don't stack up when there's multiple elements assign to one side though.

Answer (score 0):

1st property:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

2nd property(media query added for certain resolution):

```
.container{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.1stDiv{
    margin-right: auto;
}
.2ndDiv{
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

**margin-left:auto** and **margin-right: auto** works like a float for a flexbox.

OTHER IDEA FOR THE RESPONSIVE VERSION:

```
.container{
        flex-direction: column;
    }    
.1stDiv{
    align-self: flex-start;
}
.2ndDiv{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: But this will not make them horizontally align when there is space like image nr 1

Comment: They still do not align horizontally

Answer (score 0):

```
#first{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  right:auto;
  top:0px;
  background-color:red;
}

#second{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  left:auto;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelian/2r8tjbwg/)

Comment: This does not work for the wrapping effect I want to achieve like image nr 2

Comment: You can try to use bootstrap.